# Am I allowed to use an enclosed flame gas cooker during the outdoor fire ban in Sweden

Tags: sweden, local-knowledge

There is a fire ban in Sweden because of the drought and forest fire danger. It of course includes open fires, charcoal grills and the like. But I can't find information explicitly about non-open fires like gas cookers. Specifically we have a "Campingaz Party Grill 200" where the flame is pretty much enclosed.

[image]

Would this be allowed?

Comment: You might want to edit the title or the question a little, as the title asks if the ban includes your cooker, while the question asks if you're allowed to use your cooker.

Comment: @HenricF you have a point. I also enhanced the question a little.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd probably not be allowed to use your gas cooker. The following answer is written regarding the Stockholm County (as the counties are responsible for the bans). But as the bans are based on the recommendations from the Civil Contingencies Agency, they are most likely similar in other counties.

The information can be found [here](https://www.lansstyrelsen.se/download/18.4da86a5a16488a299bcb390/1533025586337/affisch-eldningsf%C3%B6rbud.pdf) and states that:

> Förbudet omfattar alla former av öppen eld, till exempel att grilla på iordning- ställda grillplatser samt att använda trangiakök, stormkök eller medtagen grill.

My translation:

> All types of open fire are prohibited, eg BBQ-ing and using “outdoor kitchens” or your own BBQ.

The FAQ on [Stockholm County (Swedish Only)](https://www.lansstyrelsen.se/stockholm/krismeddelande-i-sidhuvudet/2018-07-25-eldningsforbud-i-stockholms-lan.html#Text2) states that:

> **Får jag använda friluftskök i tält?** Ja, om tältet står på din egen tomt. Annars inte eftersom tält står utomhus på marken.

My translation:

> **Can I use an outdoor kitchen in a tent?** Yes, if the tent is in your own yard. Otherwise not, as the tent is outdoors, on the ground.

However, the same page also states that you might use an outdoor kitchen on a camping ground, provided that the kitchen is on a platform and not touching the ground.

Comment: That's very helpfull information. Thank you! I'll give it a few hours before I'll accept to see what other answers might turn up.

Comment: Generally, fixed kitchens are allowed, mobile kitchens are not, European camping grounds often have indoor kitchen facilities for guests: use those.  In any case, the camping ground reception will almost certainly prominently display fire bans.

Answer (score 6):

We are now in Skåne county and the formulation is quite clear here:

> includes **all type of** grills and **fuels**

(emphasis mine)

[image: warning sign of Skåne county]